# On iOS: How to remove MouseDown delay of 800 ms at bottom edge screen?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

When I tap on a control near the bottom edge of the screen, the MouseDown event is fired with a delay of around 800 ms.
This makes my app feel very sluggish.
I discovered however, that if I tap while moving my finger horizontally (swipe), the MouseDown event is fired immediately.

I know that iOS has a default delay of 300 ms in its Gesture Recognizer to detect if the user wanted to swipe up the iOS control panel
(the one where you can turn on/off the airplane mode, wifi, bluetooth, etc).
Somehow Delphi turned 300 ms into 800 ms...

The native solution to remove the 300 ms delay seems to be to use `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer`, which I did not find anywhere in the Delphi FMX sourcecode, and I am not sure it will solve it since Delphi somehow increased the delay, which suggests something else is going on.

How do I remove the 800 ms delay for the MouseDown?﻿

PS. I use Delphi 10 upd 1, X code 7.2 on OS X Yosemite and iOS 9.2.1

Comment: This is still an issue in Delphi Alexandria.

Comment: @havrlisan Thank you for notifying. I forgot completely about this question when I found the solution some time ago. I have posted it as the answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not yet supported by Delphi (as of Delphi 11), but luckily David Nottage has fixed this in his `KastriFree` library. The direct link to the demo app that implements the solution is here:
https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/KastriFree/tree/master/Demos/iOSGestureLag